# Вылетает приложение при симуляции Android

Tags: android, gif

Приложение стало крашить, после того, как начал использовать `pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView` . Всё по правилам, как в гайде, только крашить стало. Краш именно в следующем:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/catonstart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonCreators"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.351" />
```

Если закомментировать, то крашей нет. Прикрепляю логи:

```
08-09 22:46:07.305 4973-4973/com.example.meow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.meow, PID: 4973
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.meow/com.example.meow.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.meow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.example.meow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.meow:drawable/catonstart" (7f080061)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f080061 a=-1 r=0x7f080061}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
        at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView.<init>(GifImageView.java:40)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.example.meow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
08-09 22:46:14.538 4973-4973/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4973 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Удаляй по одному свойству и смотри, что вызывает падение приложения.

Comment: Ошибка говорит что нет картинки - может быть не в ту папку положили?

Comment: Вот ваша ошибка из вашего лога: `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.meow:drawable/catonstart" (7f080061)  is not a Drawable (color or path)`. Похоже, что у вас там не картинка. Возможно неподходящий тип файла.